# Execute commands on hidden files

Tags: files, hidden-files

I run command to search for phrase in all files:

```
cat *.* | grep blabla
```

It works fine but I got problem with hidden files and directories. Command simply not deals with them. Ho to solve this problem?

Comment: So you are looking for files something like `file1.txt` AND `.bashrc` ?

Comment: If you want to also `cat` from hidden files you'll have to eliminate that first `*`. You could do something like `cat *.* | grep blabla && cat .* | grep blabla`. By the way, if you want to `cat` all the files in a directory you could simple use `cat *`.

Comment: @EduardoCola You mean `cat *.* | grep blabla; cat .* | grep blabla`; in your command, if the first command exits with a nonzero status the second won't be executed, which is not what you want. But there's a better method for this -- please see my answer below.

Comment: For the record, it's also useless use of cat

Comment: @Serg This also was in my answer :)

Comment: @dr01 yes , i did see that, hence +1ed

Comment: WARNING: Most methods to include files starting with a dot in a command's argument list will also include the directory link ".." . Combine that with any recursive command, and the consequences can be ... intense.

Comment: @Serg This is not an entirely useless use of `cat`. It will actually concatenate the files and pipe the concatenated result to `grep`. You could not have used `<*` in place of it. And `grep blabla *` would produce a different result, because it will include the name of each file in the output, which would not happen with `cat`. If you can remember that `grep` has a `-h` option, you can avoid using `cat`. But if you don't recall that option it may well be faster to use `cat` than to look it up in the `grep` man page.

Comment: Are you sure `*.*` is really what you wanted to write in the first place? It will match entries which have a `.` in their name but skip all those with no `.` in their name. I think what you really wanted was `*`.

Answer (score 7):

By default, hidden files (i.e. those starting with a period) are excluded from the bash shell's glob expansion. However you can alter that using the `dotglob` setting e.g.

```
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/.hidden dir/visible

$ echo dir/*
dir/visible

$ shopt -s dotglob
$ echo dir/*
dir/.hidden dir/visible
```

You can unset the option afterwards with `shopt -u dotglob`

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` command with logical OR flag (`-o` )  and `-exec . . .\+` flag

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 \( -iname "*.*" -o -iname ".*"   \) -exec grep "MySearchTerm" {} \+
```

Explanation:

- `find` is a recursive command that searches files in specified directory. In this case , it is `.` the current working directory.
- `-maxdepth` flag tells us to stay only in current directory. If you want to go recursivelly or specify how many subdirectories to descent, change `1` to number of levels you wanna go.
- `\( . . .\)` part prevents shell of treating that as subshell, rather treating it as grouping of arguments to `find`.
- `-iname` flags allow specifying for which filenames to search.
- `-o` flag will tell find to search for files `*.*` or files that start with leading dot , the hidden files.
- `-exec . . .{}` structure allows running specific command to operate on files found. `\+` will tell `find` to take all the files as arguments for the command you want to run, in this case `grep`.

Here's a small example, where you can see `SEARCHFILE.txt` and `.SEARCHFILE.txt` are both found:

```
DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ find . -maxdepth 1 \( -iname "*.*" -o -iname ".*"   \) -exec grep "HelloWorld" {} \+ 2>/dev/null           
./SEARCHFILE.txt:HelloWorld ! I'm found
./localDir.txt:HelloWorld.so
./localDir.txt:HelloWorld.c
Binary file ./2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy.img matches
./.SEARCHFILE.txt:HelloWorld ! I'm found
```

Answer (score 3):

"Hidden files" are simply files whose name starts with a dot. In GUIs applications these files are usually not shown, whence their name.

You can use [shell globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html):

```
cat {*,.*} | grep blabla
```

The previous command include all files with no dot (`*`) and all files that start with a dot (`.*`).

By the way, this is an [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat), and you should instead write your command as:

```
grep blabla {*,.*}
```

Comment: Or, `cat * .* | whatever`

Comment: It also includes `.` and `..`, which sometimes may have unwanted effects. And it generates warnings if there are only hidden files.

Comment: The brace expansion is not needed, you can do just `cat * .* | grep blabla` / `grep 'blabla' * .*`.