# How do I use chown -R to include all hidden files and subdirectories except the parent directory (..)?

Tags: chown

`chown -R owner:group dir/*` doesn't change hidden files and directories that begin with '.'.
`chown -R owner:group dir/.*` seems to recursively change hidden files and directories but also changes `dir/../*` which I don't want to happen.  How do I recursively change only all files under `dir`?

Comment: `chown -hR owner:group dir`- does that work?

Comment: ... if you *must* use a glob (perhaps because you don't want to modify the ownership of `dir` itself) then you may find the bash shell's `dotglob` option useful - see for example [Execute commands on hidden files](https://askubuntu.com/a/723861/178692)

Comment: @kanehekili  That does what I want.  Thanks!